# Convert a string containing brackets and numbers to an array of floats

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

How to convert the following string to a numpy array of floats

```
'[[1.45757244e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.21294569e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.45752223e+03 1.00732059e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]'
```

Here's one approach, but it has trouble splitting out the consecutive '[' to make the cols variable

```
def str2num(str_in, np_type, shape):
    names_list = str_in.splitlines()
    tem = []
    for row in names_list:
        is_str = isinstance(row, str)
        if is_str:
            cols = [s for s in row.split(string.whitespace+'[], ') if s]
            for col in cols:
                tem.append(col)
    tem = flatten(tem)
    return np.array(tem, dtype=np_type).reshape(shape)
```

Comment: Ugg!  How did you get that?  The print string of an array is designed for conversion back. The lack of commas means it can't be evaluated as a list (of lists).  And the [] get in the way of simply splitting on white space.

Comment: Great comments, maybe I shoud just do a substitute on stuff to replace with commas, or even convert it into a list of strings separated by commas.  I'll add my code to the question.  I left the code out because I'm not sure I'm on the right path.

Comment: The context where this comes up most often is in loading a `pandas` dataframe `csv` that had arrays in individual cells.  `pandas` could only write the `str(array)` to the `csv`, which it then loaded as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the spaces in your string with commas, you then have a valid JSON string that you can read using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json
import numpy as np
 
s = '''
[[1.45757244e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.21294569e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.45752223e+03 1.00732059e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
'''
 
a = np.array(json.loads(s.replace(' ', ',')), dtype=float)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1.45757244e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.21294569e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.45752223e+03 1.00732059e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: I'm going to use your answer, but will add my answer below, which is a lot harder than what you implemented.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach

```
def str2num(str_in, np_type, shape):
    names_list = str_in.splitlines()
    tem = []
    for row in names_list:
        is_str = isinstance(row, str)
        if is_str:
            cols = [s for s in row.split() if s]
            cols = [s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '') for s in cols]
            for col in cols:
                tem.append(col)
    tem = flatten(tem)
    return np.array(tem, dtype=np_type).reshape(shape)

str_in = '''
[[1.45757244e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.21294569e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 1.45752223e+03 1.00732059e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]
'''
 
np_type = np.float
shape = (3, 3)
a = str2num(str_in, np_type, shape)
```